# How can I modify vertical space between figure and caption?

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\setlength\fboxsep{124pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics{dummy}}
\caption{Dummy caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase vertical space between figure and caption?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Modify the lengths `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` (in the document preamble) to suit your needs:

```
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{15pt plus 3pt minus 2pt} % Chosen fairly arbitrarily
```

The default values are `10pt` and `0pt`. (The `plus` and `minus` allows the space to stretch and shrink if needed. The numbers specify how much.)

Comment: What does `plus 3pt minus 2pt` stand for?

Comment: @Ichibann: `plus` and `minus` allow the space to stretch and shrink if needed. The numbers specify how much.

Comment: Where do I put this line of code?

Comment: @LWZ: In the document preamble.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Correct be if I'm wrong, but it seems like you can place this line inside the float (e.g. figure) and then it will affect only this given float.

Comment: @Dror yes indeed it works for one specific float if you put the code inside just after the \begin command. Also it's possible to use a negative number like -5pt.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov When you say "The default values are 10pt and 0pt.", do you mean `10pt plus 0pt` or either `10pt` or `0pt`. The reason being, something unknown is causing my `\belowcaptionskip` to equal `0pt`. This is undesired. I have `caption` loaded.

Comment: @JonathanKomar If I read [the source code](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/blob/master/source/caption.dtx#L2864) correctly, the default are `\setlength\abovecaptionskip{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}% length above caption
         \setlength\belowcaptionskip{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}% length below caption`

Comment: This does not work for me. I did `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{50pt plus 10pt minus 10pt}` prior to the figure, and the spacing increases after the caption instead of before it.

Answer (score 67):

`\vspace*{-10mm}` placed before `\caption` command does the trick. Just pick the number that works for you the best.

Comment: welcome, maybe using package `caption` would be a better approach? A global definition is almost always better than setting stuff by hand.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me! I needed to tweak the distance of a single figure, which on the bottom has only a thin, vertical line. This line caused the bulk of the figure to move too far up. In my experience, these sort of cases are best solved locally with small hacks like this.

Comment: This works great if you want to configure only one figure. The accpepted answer will adjust all figures in your document.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

You can use the [`caption` package](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) for this:

```
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption} % example skip set to 2pt
```

This will effect all figures.

The documentation says:

> The vertical space between the caption and the figure or table contents is controlled by the option skip=amount. The standard LATEX document classes
>   article, report and book preset it to skip=10pt, but other document classes may use a different amount.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the `\vspace*{-3mm}` option

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.74\textwidth]{figs/Subplt.pdf}
    \vspace*{-3mm}
    \caption{Inverter-level and macro-level MAPE bootstrap distributions.}
    \label{Fig:Subplt_fig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome. I wouldn't recommend this at all. I recommend to use the clean solution presented in the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm sure this is a hack with horrible side-effects, but it's a hack that just let me claw back under the page limit before a submission deadline, so on that basis, it was useful to know about and did the job.

Comment: If you use this be aware of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686212/250119 . Can't really recommend.