# How to reduce space between image and its caption?

Tags: graphics, captions

I m importing one image in latex document. But caption has bigger font than my normal text on page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

  Some text...

  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
  \end{center}
  \end{figure}

   More text...

  \end{document}
```

How to reduce the font size of caption and space between caption and image?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can do it with `caption` package. The space between the caption and the figure is called `skip` (default is 10pt).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %% Remove [demo] in your file
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}     %% Adjust here
%or equivalently 
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\begin{document}

  Some text...

  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
  \end{center}
  \end{figure}

   More text...

  \begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{This is a table.}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 7 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

     More text...

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `\captionsetup{font=small,skip=0pt}` affects both tables and figures. If you want it separately, you may use:

```
 \captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=0pt}
```

for tables only or

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,skip=0pt}
```

for figures only.

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to contain the explanation but you already have it in yours so I am deleting my answer :)

Comment: As much as I enjoy earning reputation, I enjoy better answers more. `:)` Making mine better is out of the question since it *will* look like a duplicate of your answer. +1 anyway.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Nice of you. I basically enjoy troubleshooting (and learning in turn). Everything comes next `:-)`

Comment: Can we do the same for table?

Comment: @user15662 The setup here will affect both figures and tables. If you want to separate caption settings for tables and figures set `\captionsetup[table]{}` and `\captionsetup[figure]{}` separately.

Comment: How do I change the value of skip locally ? Not for all the document.

Comment: @LMT-PhD Put `\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0pt}` inside `\begin{figure}` (just after `\begin{figure}` say), then it is local.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: @LMT-PhD Doen't work is not giving any hint. `\begin{figure}[htb]  \captionsetup{font=small,skip=0pt}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1in,width=1in,angle=-90]{foo}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
  \end{figure}` works for me.

Comment: @Kumar: For me adding \captionsetup does nothing, whether inside figure environment or just before it.

Comment: When using this solution, my figure numbers were replaced with question marks in the text.

Comment: For people who use subcaption package: you can also give the option `skip` to subcaption package

Comment: your way saved my work! thanks

Comment: 2023 update: `\captionsetup[table]{..., aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt}` works. They accept negative values as well.

Answer (score 13):

For locally change the caption position you can also use a negative value on the setting. For example, when the figure has larger white part, e.g use `\vspace{-1cm}`, instead of changing the figure itself.

Answer (score 11):

A brute force `\vspace{1pt}` just before the caption, inside any figure, also works if one wants to change spacings locally.

Comment: *Always*? Surely not. This should add absolutely no correction in terms of the vertical spacing (since you've added 0pt). Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you replace 0 with other numbers of course. I edited the answer for clarity, thank you.

Comment: This didn't work for me when using multi-line captions

Answer (score 8):

Just add a `vspace*{-3mm}`:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.74\textwidth]{figs/Subplt.pdf}
    \vspace*{-3mm}
    \caption{Inverter-level and macro-level MAPE bootstrap distributions.}
    \label{Fig:Subplt_fig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Same here as with your other answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45996/14470) suggests to modify `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`, e.g. with

`\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{15pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}`

in the preamble.
The [defaults](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/blob/5f9eef46337b547e3f0b50bbf29e2cde975d108d/source/caption.dtx#L7324) appear to be `2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt`.