# How to remove space between table and caption?

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reduce space between image and its caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94016/how-to-reduce-space-between-image-and-its-caption)

I am working on one example in which i need to draw one table and its caption. How can i control the space between Title, Table and caption. I want to minimize the spacing.

```
 \usepackage{transparent}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{hyphenat}
 \usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage{forloop}
 \usepackage{collcell}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
 \fancyfoot{}
 \begin{document}

 \arrayrulecolor{white}


  \definecolor{maincol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}   
 \definecolor{textcol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}  
 \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\collectcell\AddBreakableChars}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}


 \captionsetup[table]{aboveskip=0pt} 
 \captionsetup[table]{belowskip=10pt} 
 \textcolor{textcol}{\textbf{ XYZ }}   
  \scriptsize  

 \arrayrulecolor{white} 
 \begin{longtable}{|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1cm}|M{3.7cm}|M{1.8cm}|M{1.4cm}|} 
 \rowcolor{maincol} \textbf{ \textcolor{white}{A}} &\textbf{      \textcolor{white}{B}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{C}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{D}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{E}}  &\textbf{    \textcolor{white}{F} }\\ 
 \hline 
 \rowcolor{rowcol} 
  AA 
   &  AA&  A&  DDD  & [1, 2]  &  TTT \\ 
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{rowcol} 
    & & & & Total  & TTT \\ 
    \end{longtable} 
    \scriptsize  
     \textit{This is Caption} 
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your purpose you can set `skip=0pt` using the `caption`-package.

As was asked by the OP:

> How can i control the font size of caption?

```
font={<font options>}
```

The available optiones are: `scriptsize`, `footnotesize`, `small`, `normalsize`,
 `large` and `Large`. Simply add this to your `captionsetup`.

For other options regarding the captions, you should check out the [documentation](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

**Here an example.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item}             \\
\cline{1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\hline
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The classic}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: iamge]

Comment: Great! How can i control the font size of caption?

Comment: Depending on what you want: `font=large`, `font=small` pr in general `font=[fontsize]` (note that note all sizes are useable).

Comment: Where to write this font=small, in caption

Comment: I edited my answer so it should be clear, but here how it can be done: `\captionsetup{skip=0pt,font=small}`.

Comment: Works nicely. Is there any way to do this only locally for one table?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for giving your entire document `;-)`. However, for tables the best practice is to put the captions above the table. In your case putting `skip=0pt` and putting the caption above the longtable :

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{transparent}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{hyphenat}
 \usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage{forloop}
 \usepackage{collcell}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
 \fancyfoot{}
% \begin{document}

 \arrayrulecolor{white}

  \definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}
  \definecolor{maincol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}   
 \definecolor{textcol}{rgb}{.118, .565, 1.00}  
 \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\collectcell\AddBreakableChars}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \begin{document}
 \captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt}        %% here
% \captionsetup[table]{belowskip=10pt} 
 \textcolor{textcol}{\textbf{ XYZ }}   
  \scriptsize  
 \arrayrulecolor{white} 
 \begin{longtable}{|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1cm}|M{3.7cm}|M{1.8cm}|M{1.4cm}|} 
 \caption{this is caption}\\\hline                                       %% caption here
 \rowcolor{maincol} \textbf{ \textcolor{white}{A}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{B}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{C}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{D}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{E}}  &\textbf{    \textcolor{white}{F} }\\ 
 \hline 
 \rowcolor{rowcol} 
  AA  &  AA&  A&  DDD  & [1, 2]  &  TTT \\ 
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{rowcol} 
    & & & & Total  & TTT \\ 
    \end{longtable} 
    \scriptsize  
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `caption` of `table`s and `figure`s is inserted through a syntax:

```
\caption[short caption]{long caption}
```

where `short caption` is used for running content like `header`s and `list of table`s and `long caption` is what is seen above the table. Also, in `long table`, the width of the caption is fixed at `4in` by default. You may change the width by putting a suitable value in

```
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{5in}
```

in your preamble if you have a broader caption.

Comment: How can i move XYZ bit down?

Comment: @user15662: Already `skip=0pt`. That means the intermediate space is only the `baselineskip`. If you want to reduce that also (which I think a bad idea), use something like `\textcolor{textcol}{\textbf{ XYZ }}
 \vspace{-.5\baselineskip} `