# Reducing vertical space between figure and caption

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reduce space between image and its caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94016/how-to-reduce-space-between-image-and-its-caption)

How do I reduce the space below figures and above their captions, without changing the parameters for tables?

For example, I can do

```
\addtolength{\abovecaptionskip}{-0.25cm}
```

but it modifies the space for both figures and tables. With the `.sty` I am using now the spacing for tables are just fine and I don't want to change it.

Comment: For these jobs, using the `caption` package is probably the best.

Comment: You could give `\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup[figure]{skip=...}` a try

Comment: This is a duplicate [How can I modify vertical space between figure and caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45990) but I would suggest adding an answer in the link re `caption` package. but since this one is only after changing the setup for figures and not tables, then perhaps an edit of the title is in order? Although, afaik, there seems to be a dupe of that too somewhere.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks! If you'd like to you can put it in answer,  then I will set it as the accepted answer.