# How to remove space between a specific image and its caption

Tags: captions

In this post ([How to reduce space between image and its caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94016/how-to-reduce-space-between-image-and-its-caption)) there is an excellent explanation about the way you can reduce space between figures and its captions.

The problem is it works for every figure in the document. How could I change the space between a specific image (just one) and its caption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and its `skip` key inside a `\captionsetup` with local effect (use the desired length instead of the `0pt` I chose for the example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo: You are faster than even before ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar ;-)