# "\vspace{-number cm}" between "subfigure" and "subcaption" works in back direction in LaTeX

Tags: subcaption, vspace

Sometimes I need to reduce the space between sub figures and sub captions, so I insert `\vspace{-number cm}` to do that. But, it will increase the space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\par
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\vspace*{-0.2cm}
\caption{Test1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\vspace*{-0.2cm}
\caption{Test2}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test4}
\end{subfigure}\\
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is very weird. How should I reduce the space between sub figures and sub captions?

Thanks.

Comment: Potentially related: [spacing - How can I modify vertical space between figure and caption? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45990/how-can-i-modify-vertical-space-between-figure-and-caption) or [spacing - The space between the table and its caption is very small - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58674/the-space-between-the-table-and-its-caption-is-very-small/58684#58684) or [graphics - How to reduce space between image and its caption? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94016/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX starts horizontal mode when a image is inserted by `\includegraphic`. I.e. the image is a first letter of a paragraph. Then a space is here from the end of line a then `\vadjust` which is a primitive used by the `\vspace` macro. Then the `\caption` finalizes the paragraph using `\par` and starts a new paragraph.

The width of the image is exactly equal to current `\hsize` value, so the space between image and `\vadjust` is good beak point and the paragraph is broken here. So, you have image at the first line and `\vadjust` plus glue from `\parfillskip` at the second (unwanted) line. After this line, the material from `\vadjust` (i.e. `\vskip-0.2cm`) is inserted.

If you remove the space between the image and the `\vadjust`, i.e. write:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
```

(note the percent character), then the following `\vadjust` immediately follows after the image and only single-line paragraph is created, no unwanted line is here.

Another solution: use `\vskip-0.2cm` primitive instead `\vspace` macro. This primitive inserts `\par` before it, i.e. the paragraph is finalized as one-letter paragraph with the image only and no unwanted line is here. This is because the `\par` primitive removes the last glue from the horizontal list (the glue inserted here from the space at the end of line).

I recommend to use `\vskip` instead `\vspace` always because `\vspace` brings much less trouble: `\vskip` doesn't insert any obscure `\vadjust` and the horizontal mode is finalized before`\vskip` which is more understandable behavior.

Note that you have another bug in your code: the last `\\` in your code is used at the end of the paragraph which consists from four "letters": subfigure, subfigure, break, subfigue, subfigure. The `\\` works like `\vfil\break` in this context. If it is used at the end of the paragraph then a new unwanted underfull empty line is created and the Underfull hbox warning message is printed as you can see in your log file.

Answer (score 4):

The right tool for reducing the space between the subfigure and the subcaption is acting on the setup. The command `\vspace` is out of place here.

Use blank lines rather than `\\`. The code will be more readable and more easily maintainable. I also added some vertical separation between the two rows of subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=2pt}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test2}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test4}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the space of the specified graphs?

Comment: @Y.zeng Sorry, what space? If you want to modify a *single* subcaption, you can use `\captionsetup` inside the `subfigure` environment.

Comment: Good way. Just the space between figure and its caption.