# How to increase space between the bottom border of a boxed figure and its caption?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions

I am trying to generate a space (6pt) between the boxed figure and its caption.
Since I am using tikz code \includegraphics did not work. Also I tried `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{6pt}`, `\captionsetup[figure]{skip=6pt}`. However they did not work. How to handle this problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float,lipsum}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1]
\filldraw[black]
(0,0) circle (2pt) (1,1) circle (2pt) (1,-1) circle (2pt)
(3,1) circle (2pt) (3,-1) circle (2pt) (4,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,-1) -- (0,0);
\draw (1,1) -- (3,1) -- (4,0) -- (3,-1) -- (3,1);
\draw (3,-1) -- (1,-1)--(1,1);
\draw (3,1)-- (3,-1); \draw (4,0) -- (0,0);
\node[above] at (1,1) {$v_1$};
\node[left] at (0,0) {$v_0$};
\node[below] at (1,-1) {$v_5$};
\node[below] at (3,-1) {$v_4$};
\node[right] at (4,0) {$v_3$};
\node[above] at (3,1) {$v_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$G$.}
\label{factorex}
\end{center} 
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes there are packages unused for the solution of the problem. I wrote them just in case.

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment. Rather use the declaration `\centering`.

Comment: But using \centering or \begin{center} are the same? My problem is actually space between the borders of the box and the caption. I think it is caused because of the \floatstyle{boxed} style. But I could not find out how to fix.

Comment: @Werner Please consider re-opening the question, it asks about increasing the space above caption and the question you are referring to as duplicate discusses centering the figure (totally another issue).

Comment: @egreg Please consider re-opening the question, it asks about increasing the space above caption and the question you are referring to as duplicate discusses centering the figure (totally another issue).

Comment: @AboAmmar: You're correct. It's actually a duplicate of [How can I modify vertical space between figure and caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45990/5764) I've voted to re-open and will vote-to-close again once it is open.

Comment: @Werner I think no, even this is not a duplicate, the answer there will not work here either because the OP is using the `floatrow` which will affect any `\abovecaptionskip`

Comment: I viewed all the former questions related to my question (also  How can I modify vertical space between figure and caption?). However, none of them answered my question. As I mentioned I tried using \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{6pt}, \captionsetup[figure]{skip=6pt}. They did not work. Thanks.. @AboAmmar

Comment: @ZehraNurÖzbay I will post my answer as soon as the question is re-opened

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\floatsetup[figure]{%
style=Boxed,captionskip=12pt,capposition=bottom,margins=centering,%
}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1]
\filldraw[black]
(0,0) circle (2pt) (1,1) circle (2pt) (1,-1) circle (2pt)
(3,1) circle (2pt) (3,-1) circle (2pt) (4,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,-1) -- (0,0);
\draw (1,1) -- (3,1) -- (4,0) -- (3,-1) -- (3,1);
\draw (3,-1) -- (1,-1)--(1,1);
\draw (3,1)-- (3,-1); \draw (4,0) -- (0,0);
\node[above] at (1,1) {$v_1$};
\node[left] at (0,0) {$v_0$};
\node[below] at (1,-1) {$v_5$};
\node[below] at (3,-1) {$v_4$};
\node[right] at (4,0) {$v_3$};
\node[above] at (3,1) {$v_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$G$.}
\label{factorex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `floatrow` package and the `caption` package play roles with one another. The `floatrow` package can even have command over the `caption` package, that is why setting any `\abovecaptionskip` by `caption` will have no effect. However, we can pass the `captionskip=<length>` option to the `\floatsetup` for the `floatrow`. Only `caption` will be required to set the font size of captions. I cleaned the code by removing extra/duplicate packages and used a single `\floatsetup` including the required settings.

Comment: Thank you.. your prompt reply is appreciated :) It is ok now @AboAmmar